# Scripting language in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs, content-area

Disclaimer - Newbie to ExactTarget and AMPScript

Aside from Javascript and AMPScript, what languages (if any) are accepted as scripting languages in ExactTarget?

We have a Content Area full of a script that some consultants wrote and they left no comments or documentation on it. Now I have to edit the script and can't determine the language.

The full script is in a **content area** that is then called via a Script Interaction with this Javascript:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    try {
        var stream = ContentAreaByName("Content_Area_Name_Here");
        Write(TreatAsContent(stream));    
    } catch(e) {
        Write(Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

When I go into the content area to look at the code, it doesn't look like AMPScript to me, but if I try and debug it as JavaScript Visual Studio doesn't seem to accept it as valid Javascript.

Here's a sample of the script in the content area:

```
  var batch = lookupDE(page.settings.masterDE, 200, "MessageNumber",0);
  writeLn("Batch size: " + batch.length);

  for (i in batch) {
  var data = lookupDE(batch[i].MasterDE, 1, "ContactID", batch[i

].ContactID);

            // -- UPSERT EXTRACURRICULAR ACTIVITY
var extraCurricular = {"object":"TargetX_SRMb__Extra_Curricular_Activity__c","uniqueKey":[],"updateFields":[], "createFields" : []};
extraCurricular.uniqueKey.push({"field": "TargetX_SRMb__Contact__c", "value": row.ContactID });
extraCurricular.uniqueKey.push({"field": "Name", "value": "Sophomore Postcard" });
extraCurricular.updateFields.push({"field":"Fulfillment_Status__c", "value" : "Pending"});
extraCurricular.updateFields.push({"field":"Source__c", "value" : "Campaign"});
          SalesforceUpsert(extraCurricular);
         // -- EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITY OBJECT

   } // for BATCH

  page.logArr.push({"end": Now()});
  writeLn( Stringify(page.logArr) );

  /* ====== FUNCTIONS ======= */
  function write(str){
    !str ? str = '' : str;
    if(debug){
      Write(str);
    }
  }
  function writeLn(str){
    !str ? str = '' : str;
    if(debug){
      write(str + '<br/>');
    }
  }

  function lookupDE(deName, max, keyName, keyValue) {
    var rtn = {};
    if (keyValue == "") {
      page.logArr.push({"errorLocation":"lookupDE","value":"keyValue blank"});
    } else {
      try {
        // attempt lookup row
        //***var DE1 = DataExtension.Init(deName);
        //***var data1 = DE1.Rows.Lookup(keyName, keyValue);
        var data1 = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows(deName, max,'InsertDate DESC',keyName,keyValue);
        page.results.lookupDESuccess = 1;
        return data1;
      } catch (e1) {
          page.logArr.push({"errorLocation":"lookupDE","value":e1});
      }
    }
  }
```

Any ideas how I can validate my edits to this script or at the very least determine exactly what it is so I can research the language before just editing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Marketing Cloud SSJS, so the functions used aren't available in native javascript. These modules/functions are loaded by marketing cloud and allow reading from dataextensions, etc. so the functions only work within marketing cloud.

Information on Server-Side JavaScript can be found here: [**Server-Side JavaScript Syntax Guide**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. I was wondering why it looked like Javascript but Visual Studio was rejecting it. I hasn't found that documentation previously.